# (R Shiny + igraph) handling reactivity to current list of vertices in updateSelectInput

Tags: r, shiny, igraph

I'm writing a simple app that shows an igraph plot and allows me to select a vertex to delete.

[image]

The list of vertices isn't updating correctly after deletion with `updateSelectInput` and I can't point at how I'm handling reactivity wrong. The app erases a single vertex and doesn't allow the user to erase another.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(igraph)


##################################################
# Define UI 
###################################################
g <- make_ring(10)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Delete vertices in graph"),

   # select with list of vertices in graph 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("vertexToDelete",
                     "Vertex to delete",
                     choices = V(g),
                     width = "100px"),

         actionButton("goButtonDelete", 
                      "Evaluate", 
                      width = '160px')
         ),



      # Show a plot of the graph
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("graphPlot")
      )
   )
)
#################################################################################
# Define server logic 
#################################################################################


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$graphPlot <- renderPlot({

     if(input$goButtonDelete !=0)
      isolate({
         g <- delete_vertices(g, input$vertexToDelete)
         print(g)
         updateSelectInput(session, "vertexToDelete", choices = V(g))
       })

     plot(g) 
    })
  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```

Comment: you should define `g` before using it in the ui,....

Comment: @BigDataScientist: oh yes, I did that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deletion is not persisted because `g <- delete_vertices(g, input$vertexToDelete)` actually does not modify the global `g` object. Instead it creates a local  `g` that is then printed and plotted. The global `g` remains unchanged and is used the next time.

You could use `g <<- delete_vertices(g, input$vertexToDelete)` to modify the global object, but a more elegant way is to use `reactiveValues` to trigger the plot when the graph is updated.

The second issue is that you use unnamed vertices, and this is why it seems it is always the last one (10, 9...) that is deleted. You can use `set_vertex_attr(g, "name", ...)` to name vertices (and then `V(g)$name` to access their name)

Finally, you can use `observeEvent` to perform the deletion when the actionButton is clicked:

```
g <- make_ring(10) %>% set_vertex_attr("name", value = LETTERS[1:10])

ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Delete vertices in graph"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("vertexToDelete", "Vertex to delete", choices=V(g)$name),
      actionButton("goButtonDelete", "Evaluate")
    ),
    # Show a plot of the graph
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graphPlot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my <- reactiveValues(g=g)

  observeEvent(input$goButtonDelete,{
    my$g <- delete_vertices(my$g, input$vertexToDelete)
    updateSelectInput(session, "vertexToDelete", choices=V(my$g)$name)
    })

  output$graphPlot <- renderPlot(plot(my$g))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you, this solves most of my issues except one: the labels of the vertices get reassigned in the plot after each delete. If I delete vertex 1, it keeps appearing in the selectInput input options as the indices get reassigned.

Comment: I get an "object g not found" error when using your code above. This is due to  set_vertex_attr("name", value = seq_along(g)) at the start, I changed the seq_along(g) to LETTERS[1:10] to get it to run, and now the app isn't working.

Comment: I does work for me with `LETTERS[1:10]`... I'm using R version 3.3.2, Windows 7, igraph_1.0.1, shiny_1.0.3. Do you have error message?

Comment: also works here (R version 3.4.0, Windows 7, igraph_1.0.1, shiny_1.0.3)

Comment: I'm running R 3.3.1, Ubuntu 14.04, shiny 0.14.2, igraph 1.01.The current version above does work!